# How to know which algorithm technique or deep learning model best for some specific dataset

Tags: python, time, dataset, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset with series of input which generate only two values 1 and 2.
Each day it has 288 values which are randomly generate sequence of 1 and 2.
This process continue upto 45 days with some sequence which system generate.
Now i want to predict sequence of values (1,2) for day 46.

I tried different machine learning algorithm like SVM, RNN but did't get more than 55 % accuracy

Comment: make sure you have balance set of input sequence in your data set. 50% 1 sequence and 50% 2 sequence.

Comment: yes , i have a input of 45 days in which every day have 288 entries, but i want to predict day 46 entries . So what can i do else?

Comment: do you want to predict the sequence of 288 entries on day 46? Do you have some example data?

Comment: yes, i want to predict day 46 entries and  i have a dataset with values of only o and 1.